# How to detect ethernet uplink speed on CentOS 6 OpenVZ VPS

Tags: vps, ethernet, ethtool, lspci

I recently purchased a VPS which was advertised as a 100Mbps uplink but the promotion promised a free upgrade to a 1Gbps uplink. I'm trying to find out if I received the upgrade with various methods without any luck.

Running `lspci` I get:

```
[root@host ~]# lspci
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.
[root@host ~]#
```

Similarly, running `lshw` and `ethtool` does not show any network information either.

`ifconfig -a` shows:

```
[root@host /]# ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:97474 (95.1 KiB)  TX bytes:97474 (95.1 KiB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:256143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:177324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:280427908 (267.4 MiB)  TX bytes:76882233 (73.3 MiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:198.xx.xxx.xx  P-t-P:198.xx.xxx.xx  Bcast:198.xx.xxx.xx  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
[root@host /]#
```

Perhaps this server doesn't have PCI, if that is the case is there any other way to find out the uplink speed?

Comment: What type of virtualization is in use?

Comment: @MichaelHampton OpenVZ

Comment: That explains your problem. (And every other problem you're going to have in future...)

Comment: @MichaelHampton There's nothing wrong with OpenVZ, it's actually better then Virtuozzo from HostGator. They charged me $20.00 a month for 300mb of ram and 677mhz cpu and took a good minute to shutdown. OpenVZ reboots in under 2 seconds, can't beat that quality.

Comment: Virtuozzo and OpenVZ are practically identical. The cost of one provider or another has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Are you saying there is no way to check the network uplink speed with a OpenVZ virtualization?

Comment: I have to agree with @MichaelHampton - OpenVZ is not helpful here. It is not a "true" virtualization platform (ie, Type 1) such as Xen, VMware et al. You don't actually have you own kernel instance with an OpenVZ - you're running a shared kernel will the host and all other containers. Without a complete kernel, you're lacking pretty much any ability to interrogate "hardware" (eg, to find ethernet link-speed)

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way to test whether you are on a 100mbps or 1gbps uplink, you download this python script for running a speed test with speedtest.net

```
wget -O speedtest-cli.py https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/raw/master/speedtest_cli.py
```

Then once you have the script you do:

```
python speedtest-cli.py --share
```

Here is my result:

[image]

Which proves my workstation is on a `full-dulpex transmission 1 gigabit per second uplink`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ethtool` with an argument for the interface e.g. `ethtool eth0`.

Dmesg may have other useful information but it is transient.

Comment: Sending `ethtool eth0` just breaks to a new line without any output. `ifconfig -a` shows: `lo`, `venet0`, `venet0:0` and doing `ethtool venet0`, etc. yields the same result.